# Pycharm: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newspaper'. Not having the problem with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, nlp, python-newspaper

Just as the title suggests.  It's not even a module I can install because it's a part of Python 3 and I'm not having any problem using it in Jupyter Notebook.

I've tried to switch the Python Interpreter from 3.8 to 3.6, to no avail.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `newspaper` is not part of Python3 on my system. The docs imply you have to install it first, `pip3 install newspaper3k`. https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh, well that's interesting.  Thanks for clarifying that.  I am confused then that one IDE accesses it and not the other.  I have them pointed in the same ENV.  I must have installed it at some point.  If I reinstall it again, (I probably used anaconda the first time), is there any risk there for conflicts?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I recommend https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to manage your python envs.